# Remove CSS atribute from body::after

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to remove the background-image attribute with jQuery but I had no success until now. The '::after' don't let me remove-it. How I can do that?

`body::after {
     background-image: url(../images/16_sm.jpg);
}`

Comment: What do you mean by "The '::after' don't let me remove-it."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

Html:

```
<body class='test'>
```

Css:

```
.test::after{
 background-image: url(../images/16_sm.jpg);
}
```

Js:

```
$('body').removeClass('test');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
$(body).css("background-image", "");
```

or

```
$(body).css("background-image", "none");
```